# Is there any difference between "character traits" and "personality traits"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, difference

As far as I understand, they are synonyms.
Is it so?
If not, then what is the difference between them?

Comment: Oxford Languages gives _personality_ as a synonym of  this sense of _character_ (the word has other meanings, of course).

Answer (score 1):

*Character trait* has something of the feeling of ethics or morality, thus including such examples as honesty, greed, generosity, and duplicity. By contrast, *personality trait* is more neutral: shyness, curiosity, talkativeness, and determination.

Comment: I agree with your distinction between character and personality, but the word **trait**  doesn't seem to fit with character in the sense of moral or ethics.  That he's a no good dirty liar isn't a "trait", or that he can be counted on to honor his word or live up to a promise isn't a "trait". So I think **trait** wrests the meaning of character away from the moral and ethical.